# how to set a specific key in a struct as a foreign key in beego orm?

Tags: go, orm, beego

I want to set the Coins struct's Address as a foreign key of Accounts struct's address, how to set it in beego orm?

```
type Coins struct {
    Id        int       `orm:"auto"`
    Address   string    `orm:"rel(fk);on_delete(cascade);on_update(cascade);index" json:"address"`
    Symbol    string    `json:"symbol"`
    Amount    float64   `orm:"digits(64);decimals(6)" json:"amount"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `orm:"auto_now_add;type(datetime)"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `orm:"auto_now_add;type(datetime)"`
}

type Accounts struct {
    Id                       int       `orm:"auto"`
    Address                  string    `orm:"index;unique" json:"address"`
    Type                     string    `json:"type"`
}
```

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

See, if this works:

```golang
type Coins struct {
    Id        int       `orm:"auto"`
    Accouts   *Accounts `orm:"rel(fk)"`
    Address   string `orm:"pk;auto;on_delete(cascade);on_update(cascade);index" json:"address"`
    Symbol    string    `json:"symbol"`
    Amount    float64   `orm:"digits(64);decimals(6)" json:"amount"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `orm:"auto_now_add;type(datetime)"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `orm:"auto_now_add;type(datetime)"`
}

type Accounts struct {
    Id                       int       `orm:"pk;auto"`
    Address                  string    `orm:"index;unique" json:"address"`
    Type                     string    `json:"type"`
}
```